# codeception unit tests run only for public function testMe

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

I created a codeception unit test:

```
<?php


use Something\SiteResultsHolder;

class ResultHolderTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
   /**
    * @var \UnitTester
    */
    protected $tester;

    protected function _before()
    {
    }

    protected function _after()
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function testMe()
    {
        //this test run

    }

    public function checkLimit() {
       //this test doesn't run
    }
}
```

I call this in terminal:

```
codecept run unit
```

but the only test call is --> testMe
and it doesn't run --> checkLimit

and they are both public.

when I do acceptance tests, all public methods are different tests but here it doesn't seem to work.

How do I add tests there? that will be called?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the PhpUnit 4.2 Documentation (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html):

> The tests are public methods that are named test*.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the @test annotation in a method's docblock to mark it as a test    method.

`\Codeception\TestCase\Test` extends `\Codeception\TestCase`, which extends `\PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase`.

Therefor you are actually working with PHPUnit. You can use the phpunit documentation as reference (https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html).

In your case:

```
public function testCheckLimit() {
}
```

or

```
/**
 * @test
 */
public function checkLimit() {
}
```

should work